# Exclude category from drop down list form

Tags: categories, forms, dropdown, exclude

I need a bit of quick help. How do I exclude category ID number 50 for example in drop down list form in Wordpress?

I have this code and I need to just insert the excluded category id.

```
<?php
$cate_id = retrieve_cat_data(true);
$cate_name = retrieve_cat_data(false);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cate_name); $i++ ) { 
?>

<option value="<?php echo $cate_id[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $cate_name[$i]; ?>
</option><?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance to everyone :)

Comment: I did do it. I'm still confused by the system and the ratings here so do forgive me.

Comment: what is `retrieve_cat_data` can we see that function?

Comment: there is no function it refers to the dropdown menu form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
$cat_to_EXCLUDE = 50;
$cate_id = retrieve_cat_data(true);
$cate_name = retrieve_cat_data(false);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cate_name); $i++ ) { 
?>
if ($cate_id[$i] != $cat_to_EXCLUDE){
<option value="<?php echo $cate_id[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $cate_name[$i]; ?>
</option><?php }} ?>
```

### update:

if you search your theme's functions.php file i bet you will find a function named `retrieve_cat_data`

anyway you can simple create a dropdown using [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)
and you can exclude a category with its `exclude` argument :

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('exclude=50'); ?>
```

Comment: UPDATE: This works great but there is an issue that appears. The form value takes the first category and makes it default in the drop down menu. But that can create problems because a user can forget to choose a proper category. Is there a way to leave the first option blank so the user is forced to choose between available categories?

Comment: Hey I've found it : if you search your theme's functions.php file i bet you will find a function named retrieve_cat_data. Here is the PASTIE CODE: http://pastie.org/2243250 HELP :D:

Comment: I've also tried this and it works: <option value="<option value="<?php wp_dropdown_categories('exclude=34, selected=0'); ?>  </option> but now I need a dummy text to replace the empty form value to : choose your category! Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude=>[single id or array of ids]` that you want to exclude in $args array. For example

```
$args = array(
'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
'show_option_none' => 'All Categories',
'orderby'          => 'name',
'echo'             => 1,
'class'            => 'product-category-dropdown',
'name'             => 'product_cat',
'selected'         => isset($_GET['product_cat']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']) : '',
'value_field'      => 'slug',
'exclude'=>array(18,38));
```

`wp_dropdown_categories($args);`